# How to use select2 plugin with php and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am new to select2 plugin, my problem is,
I want to put a job search option to my web page that is when user queries with keyword php then it will return corresponding data as json. For example if user enters java then it will return  most possible words like java, javascript, java.net and user can pick up one or more item from the list displayed.
i did but there is no select option

**script**

```
$(".load").select2({
 minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
          url: "http://localhost/testserver/Test",
      dataType: 'json',
       type: "post",

      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, page) {
      console.log(data);
        return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.Name,


                    }
                })
            };
      }

    },


});
```

**html**

```
<select class="load" style="width:400px;">
```

Comment: show what all you have tried..? is that only thing that you have now?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/x62Lwgrt/) give some idea

Answer (score 0):

Find below Complete solution

```
     $(document).ready(function() {          
            $(".load").select2({
 minimumInputLength: 2,
    ajax: {
          url: "http://ip.jsontest.com/",
      dataType: 'json',
       type: "post",

      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          q: term
        };
      },
      processResults: function (data, page) {

        return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {  console.log(item);
                    return {
                        text: item
                    }
                })
            };
      }

    },


});
});
```

I have pointed url to some other location for dynamic data..Please make changes accordingly